# Mattermost with Docker for Windows error: invalid volume specification

Tags: docker, windows-server, mattermost

I try to get Mattermost working with Docker for Windows. As mentioned [here](https://docs.mattermost.com/install/docker-local-machine.html#mac-os-x-and-windows-10) I executed the following command:

`docker run --name mattermost-preview -d --publish 8065:8065 mattermost/mattermost-preview`

After pulling and extracting the files, docker exits and throws the following error:

`docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Unrecognised volume spec: invalid volume specification: './mattermost-data'.`

Running `Windows Server 2019 PreRelease 17623` and `docker 17.10.0-ee-preview-3`

Answer (score 0):

Feedback from our engineers is that while they've never used Docker with Windows, your issue might be Windows related because it can't create a Docker volume (maybe related to the different path syntax between Linux and Windows ?)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but here are the very basic example using volume on Windows Engine.
`docker run -it -v C:\Users\Administrator\:C:\Users\public microsoft/nanoserver powershell`

Also, you might want to use stable release channel instead of pre-release version of Windows.  There are number of changes made, and base images will not be compatible.  It is likely that the author of this image built it for Windows stable release.

Maybe, contact support for Mattermost?